# Alternative to RandomAccessFile.setLength()

Tags: java, file, filesystems

In case the underlining file system does not support `RandomAccessFile.setLength(..)` operation, is there any equivalent file operation in `Java`, e.g. writing empty content until certain size?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: setLength appends data but also truncates data if the file is longer than the length specified. Do you need that function as well or are we really only talking about increasing the file-size up to a given length?

Comment: @Lothar thanks for your reply, that's a good point. I think my use case is increase, however, would be really good to learn equivalent of truncate as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the size can be done quite simply:

```
File file = new File(filename);
long destSize = 1000000;
long orgSize = file.length();
if (destiSize > orgSize) {
    long diff = destSize - orgSize;
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true)) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        while (diff > 0) {
            int len = (int) Math.min(buf.length, diff);
            fos.write(buf, 0, len);
            diff -= len;
        }
    }
}
```

Truncating is harder, because there is no method in `RandomAccessFile` or other classes, I'm aware of. The "simplest" approach is to create a new file, copy the original data to it, until `destSize` is reached, delete the old file and rename the new file to the name of the old one.